# Как организовать правильную архитектуру с WCF-сервисом в трехзвенном проекте?

Tags: wcf

Начал изучать WCF. Для своего тестового проекта решил сделать трехзвенный проект: 1) библиотека классов со всей бизнес-логикой и работой с БД на LinqToSql; 2) Библиотека службы WCF; 3) клиент ASP.NET MVC. 
Собственно загвоздка возникла в том, как лучше всего организовать связь LinqToSql - WCF. 
На данный момент интерфейсы моих LinqToSql-моделей:

```
interface IVisitor
{
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    bool Gender { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Surname { get; set; }
    System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Visit> Visit { get; set; }
}

interface IVisit
    {
        DateTime DateVisit { get; set; }
        long IdVisitor { get; set; }
        Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
    }
```

как лучше будет эти классы перенести в WCF-проект и объявить [DataContract]-ами? Проставить аттрибуты прямо в проекте бизнес-логики будет плохим тоном, тем более, что придется лезть в дизайнер dbml. 
Но будет ли хорошо по этим интерфейсам в проекте wcf-службы реализовать классы VisitorDataContract, VisitDataContract и в реализации службы приводить объект модели в объект этого класса? По сути же будет дублирование кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы называете бизнес-логикой проект, который выполняет отображение таблиц вашей бд на шарповские классы, то вы ошибаетесь. Это не бизнес-логика, это всего лишь проекция таблиц базы данных. Разумеется, как-либо редактировать эти классы, и тем более добавлять атрибуты DataContact к ним не нужно. В любом случае ваши слои (звенья, как вы их называете) должны иметь наименьший из возможных уровней связности друг с другом. Эти слои должны взаимодействовать между собой через какие-то открытые интерфейсы, и представлять собой отдельный модуль, любой из которых можно безболезненно заменить каким-то другим, не разрушая при этом всю архитектуру. Иными словами, ваша бизнес-логика не должна вообще ничего знать о ни о WCF-проекте, ни о ASP.NET MVC-проекте. WCF в  свою очередь не должен ничего знать об ASP.NET MVC, и не должен быть намертво привязан к конкретно этому слою бизнес-логики (то есть бизнес-логика дожна предоставлять некий набор точек доступа, которыми может пользоваться WCF, при этом замена вашего слоя бизнес-логики на другой, с аналогичными точками доступа, должна проходить безболезненно). Этим самым вы облегчите себе жизнь при изменении, расширении и тестировании проекта и избавитесь от необходимости писать костыли по малейшему повожу. 
Из этого следует, что работать с DataContract должен только WCF, поскольку DataContract нужен для сериализации ваших данных, а сериализация нужна только WCF-сервису. Нижележащие слои (бизнес-логика, слой данных) вообще ничего не знают о сериализации, а потому и видеть ее не должны. Меньше знаешь - крепче спишь, как известно. 
Поскольку ваш WCF-сервис будет передавать наружу какие-то данные, а брать он их, очевидно, будет из бизнес-логики, то для корректной передачи ему потребуется эти данные как-то сериализовать. Тут и пригодятся DataContract. Вам потребуется создать класс (или классы) с этим атрибутом, с помощью которых будет выполняться сериализация данных из бизнес-логики. Причем далеко не обязательно, чтобы эти классы были полными проекциями каждого класса из бизнес-логики, скорее всего это не понадобится, в противном же случае вы получите практически полное дублирование кода. Однако в целом некоего дублирования не избежать, потому что смешивать сериализацию и бизнес-логику все же не стоит, это разные вещи, и они должны быть разнесены по разным слоям вашего приложения

Comment: > Если вы называете бизнес-логикой проект, который выполняет отображение таблиц вашей бд на шарповские классы, то вы ошибаетесь. Это не бизнес-логика, это всего лишь проекция таблиц базы данных.

Это не бизнес-логика, это часть бизнес-логики. Я лишь показал интерфейсы классов, которые должны сериализоваться, и указал, что классы сериализации окажутся полной проекцией классов модели - собственно из-за такого дублирования и у меня возникли сомнения. Так у меня в проекте бизнес-логики уже есть и репозиторий linq-запросов, и валидация данных. 
Насчет остального понятно, спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: Теперь думаю, что наилучшим вариантом будет так:
<pre>
public interface IVisitorsWcfService
{
... 
[DataContract]
public class VisitorDataContract
  {
     public VisitorDataContract(Visitor visitor) {
        // заполняем объект VisitorDataContract данными из объекта Visitor 
     }
}
</pre>

И в реализации службы после вызова конструктора, уже работаем VisitorDataContract как нам заблагорассудится